# FFmpeg rtsp over http authentication

Tags: http, authentication, ffmpeg, rtsp

I am trying to connect an IP camera, in rtsp over http. I am using FFmpeg 1.0.7. The below code seems working fine if the camera is open to everyone. But if the camera requires authentication, the below code doesn't work as it doesn't pass the user credentials. I don't know how to pass the user credentials to FFMpeg library.

```
// open video stream
AVDictionary *serverOpt = NULL;

av_dict_set(&serverOpt, "rtsp_transport", "http", 0);
if (avformat_open_input(&_formatCtx, [url UTF8String], NULL, &serverOpt)!=0){
    NSLog(@"error opening stream");
    [self dealloc_helper];
    return -1; // Couldn't open file
}
```

Please advise.

Comment: what kind of authentication do you need ?
Assuming it is "basic", you can code it yourself since [the protocol](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_access_authentication) is simple

Comment: yes, I am looking for "basic" authentication. The library FFmpeg does connect with the video server, but it doesn't worked with authentication. I am finding hard to understand the FFmpeg library source code which is written in C.